# npm install Fails With "Command not found" ... ONLY With One Package?

Tags: linux, npm, npm-install

This is a weird one.  I recently setup a new (Linux) development machine, and normally `npm` works fine:

```
$ npm i cheerio
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
... rest of installation output ...
```

But when I try to install one specific package, `local-ssl-proxy`, I get an error:

```
$ npm i local-ssl-proxy
npm i local-ssl-proxy: command not found
```

(**NOTE:** The package is actually designed to be installed globally, but I get the same error when I provide a `-g` argument.)

I thought at first maybe it was the hyphens, but another hyphenated package works fine:

```
$ npm i image-size
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
... rest of installation output ...
```

Can anyone explain why some some packages would tell me `npm` doesn't exist, while some wouldn't?  I figure it has to be a Bash issue or something (I do have the `npm` Bash completions installed, although I don't see how they could cause this).

But I just don't see how failing to find the `npm` command could even be the fault of `npm`, and how my OS could fail to find `npm` *just* for one argument to the command.

Comment: The format of error seems strange. Have you tried `npm install local-ssl-proxy` or `yarn local-ssl-proxy` ?

Comment: `npm i` is a legitimate alias to `npm install`; the two are the same command.  However, when I ran either one just now, they both worked, so I have absolutely no idea what was broken ... but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem wound up fixing itself, so the solution was as strange as the issue.  I did however restart my terminal in-between, so that's the only thing I can attribute to the fix.